# R Error in sp::CRS(SRS_string = from$wkt): unused argument (SRS_string = from$wkt)

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, r, sf

A previous script that I had is no longer working after the sf package major change. I am using sf 0.9.6 and raster 3.0.2. I have tried to modify my code but cannot run `raster::extract()`.

My previous code now breaks on the second command and does not generate extent_program. I receive: `Error in sp::CRS(SRS_string = from$wkt): unused argument (SRS_string = from$wkt)`.

```
# Read in polygons from 'my_shapefile.shp'

sf_program_fallow <- 'my_shapefile.shp' %>% sf::st_read() %>% sf::st_transform(crs = 32611) 

# Generate extent of polygons (now generates error)
extent_program <- extent(sf::as_Spatial(sf_program_fallow))

# Calculate zonal statistics (note: 'my_ndvi_RasterLayer' created earlier)
ndvi_fallowed_fields <- raster::extract(x = 'my_ndvi_RasterLayer', 
                       y = sf_program_fallow,
                       method = 'simple',
                       fun = mean,
                       na.rm = T,
                       sp = TRUE)
```

Updating the first line of code to the following produces extent_program but not `ndvi_fallowed_fields`. I get the same error: `Error in sp::CRS(SRS_string = from$wkt): unused argument (SRS_string = from$wkt)`

```
sf_program_fallow <- 'my_shapefile.shp' %>% sf::st_read() %>% sf::st_transform(., sf::st_crs(32611))
```

Comment: "my_shapefile.shp" should be string, with quotes, unless you define it as my_shapefile.shp = "my_shapefile.shp"

Comment: your argument `sp = TRUE`, according to help is for spatial* objects, `sf_program_fallow` is an `sf` object; I'm not sure .img files have crs info and, also according to `extract` manual, x should be a `raster` object, not sure if it can be read from disk straight into the function

Comment: @ElioDiaz thanks so much for catching that. The 'my_ndvi_Raster.img' is actually a S4 RasterLayer.

Comment: is it working now? just answer your own question or add the fix to OP

Comment: @ElioDiaz, thanks, the code above is a truncated version of a much longer script so I haven't actually changed anything. The issue I believe lies in the recent sf change regarding coordinate reference systems.

Answer (score 2):

Two things solved this issue:

1. Updated all packages following the instructions from: https://inbo.github.io/tutorials/tutorials/spatial_crs_coding/#defining-a-crs-with-sp

- Windows users: to make sure that the rgdal and sf packages use GDAL 3 / PROJ ≥ 6 – which is now highly advised: please update all your packages in a pure R console (not RStudio) that uses your latest installed R version, by running `update.packages(ask = FALSE, checkBuilt = TRUE)`.

2. Following instructions from https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgdal/vignettes/PROJ6_GDAL3.html#Migration_to_PROJ6GDAL3
   I replaced `crs = 32611` with `SRS_string = "EPSG:32611"`.

The following is final code that ran:

```
# Updated section:
crs_wgs84utm11 <- sp::CRS(SRS_string = "EPSG:32611")
sf_program_fallow <- 'my_shapefile.shp' %>% sf::st_read() %>% sf::st_transform(crs = crs_wgs84utm11)

# unchanged:
extent_program <- extent(sf::as_Spatial(sf_program_fallow))

# Calculate zonal statistics (note: 'my_ndvi_RasterLayer' created earlier)
ndvi_fallowed_fields <- raster::extract(x = 'my_ndvi_RasterLayer', 
                   y = sf_program_fallow,
                   method = 'simple',
                   fun = mean,
                   na.rm = T,
                   sp = TRUE)
```